# Этимология слова "обитать"

Tags: этимология

В Викисловаре [пишут](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), что слово происходит от древнерусского `обитати`. Я недавно начал учить французский, там есть похожее слово с таким же значением - `habiter` (жить, обитать), которое, в свою очередь, происходит от [латинского](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habiter) слова `habitō`. Имеют ли эти слова какие-то более древние общие корни?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the French and the Russian words are not etymologically connected.

The French word derives from Latin *habito* ("I have repeatedly") which in its turn derives from *habeo* ("I have") and ultimately from PIE **gʰabʰ/gʰebʰ-* ("to give"). This word is akin to English "to give" and OCS *гобина* ("vast harvest").

Note that the "t" inside the word is a sign of frequentative, a Latin innovation. Compare *canto* ("I sing repeatedly") < *cano* ("I sing"), *dicto* ("I say repeatedly") < *dico* ("I say") etc. These words are related to English "cantata", "hen", "dictator" and "teach", respectively, but "cantata" and "dictator" have their ancestors originated in Latin and were borrowed with the Latin-originated *t*, while "hen" and "teach" were developed from the same PIE roots independently.

The Russian word can be traced to its Proto-Slavic ancestor **vitati* ("to dwell") which is akin to Baltic words meaning "place", but no further to PIE.